# Unable to install older Linux kernel version

Tags: grub2, linux-headers

I had to install an older version of linux-kernel, I used the command: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-5. 3.0-64-generic`

When I'm running command `sudo update-grub` , it doesn't list this version.

How to correct this?
And also how can I set this as a kernel to use by the system?

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  5.3 kernel is not supported (outside of a specific *cloud* infrastructure as I understand it; it was an *eoan* kernel and thus not supported outside of a specific use-case now in Ubuntu)

Comment: OS is ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the linux-image package. The linux-headers package is needed for development/compiling kernel modules, you probably don't need it.

Comment: What will be the command for it?

Comment: Just replace the headers part with image. So sudo apt-get install linux-image-5.3.0-64-generic should do it